# SQL Сrossing of time

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

There is a table with 3 columns id, start (timestamp), duration (interval). This table shows the start and duration of the scheduled online lessons. The problem is that the server is not capable of supporting more than three conferences at the same time. We need a request to determine which broadcasts or at what time intersect, in order to catch it in advance and reschedule the planned classes. For example, if there are broadcasts in

15:00 for 45 minutes

15:00 for 1 hour

15:15 for 1 hour 15 minutes

15:30 for 45 minutes

we see an intersection that our server will not "process", the request must find it and return, for example, a "bad" interval or id of these lessons. How to solve this using SQL?

```
    create table lessons 
(id bigserial not null constraint str_pkey primary key, duration interval, sch_at timestamp with time zone)
insert into lessons
 (id, sch_at, duration) values 
(1234, '2020-09-19 15:30:00.000000', '0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 15 mins 0.00 secs'), 
(1235, '2020-09-19 15:45:00.000000', '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 45 mins 0.00 secs');
```

Thanks!
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxmrU.png)

Comment: Is your interval actually stored like `1 hour 15 minutes`? Its stored as a string? Please show some real sample data.

Comment: See [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and [Range Function/Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)

Comment: its stored in interval format, added img in question, so i can summ start+duration if needed

Comment: Please do not post an image for textual information per [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Copy and paste the data as text update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of concurrent sessions at a given time using:

```
with t as (
      select sch_at as ts, 1 as inc
      from lessons t
      union all
      select sch_at + duration, -1 as inc
      from lessons t
     )
select t.*
from (select ts,
             sum(sum(inc)) over (order by ts) as num_concurrent
      from t
      group by ts
     ) t
where num_concurrent > 3;
```

Note:  This does not count overlaps where one session ends exactly when another begins.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2906a6eccd28326565fb5f9ecd5e0d47) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much! "OVER" funcs is hard for me, could u tell me should i change 't' on my table name, or 'ts'? I tried both but its still lot of errors
my columns names are id, start_time, duration and table name lessons

Comment: i think i found the mistake, comma is missed between ts and summ. but result is incorrect, num_concurrent is is ascending from 4 to infinity

Comment: unfortunately this still doesnt work for me, having mistake 'missing FROM-clause entry for table "ts"', added create and insert in the question. i also doesnt know what does .* mean, my bad sorry :(

Comment: Gordon, thanks a lot for your help. Ill stop disturbing you and ill try to find solution by myself :) I dont know the reason why output is ascending from 3 to 701 with the ts column, which is ascending too. I think that correct result should be like 4, 5, 4, 4 etc but nah :(

Comment: @Michael . . . I updated the answer based on the sample data in your question and provided a db<>fiddle.